# Allow related field in post request in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have created model with many to many relationship and I have join table when I keep additional variable for it:

```
class BorderStatus(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [("OP", "OPEN"), ("SEMI", "CAUTION"), ("CLOSED", "CLOSED")]
    origin_country = models.ForeignKey(OriginCountry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="0")
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="0")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="CLOSED")
    extra = 1
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [("destination", "origin_country")]
        verbose_name_plural = "Border Statuses"

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"{self.origin_country.origin_country.name} -> {self.destination.name}"
            f" ({self.status})"
        )
```

Other models:

```
# Create your models here.
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Country')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OriginCountry(models.Model):
    origin_country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country, related_name="origins",  on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    destinations = models.ManyToManyField(
        Country, related_name="destinations", through="BorderStatus"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Origin Countries"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.origin_country.name
```

Here is my serializer for the endpoint:

```
class BorderStatusEditorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Create serializer for editing single connection based on origin and destination name- to change status"""
    origin_country = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    destination = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BorderStatus
        fields = ('origin_country', 'destination', 'status')
```

And my endpoint:

```
class BorderStatusViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BorderStatus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BorderStatusEditorSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields=('origin_country','destination')
```

The problem Im having is that I cant create any new combination for the BorderStatus model in this serializer via post request.
If I remove the lines:

```
origin_country = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
destination = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
```

Then the form will work, but then I wont have the string representation of those variables, instead I get IDs.

Is there any way to allow request to accept `origin_country` and `destination` while being related fields?

EDIT:

To clarify how `OriginCountry` works, it is has a nested field:

```
 [{     "id": 1
        "origin_country": "Canada",
        "dest_country": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "France",
                "status": "CLOSED"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Canada",
                "status": "OP"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: For the origin country, you could use a SlugRelatedField, but for the destination, that's gonna be more tricky... How do you expect it to be created/updated ?

Comment: For the destination I still use the same list of countries that origin_country which is based on the `Country` model. I was thinking about changing primary_key to `name` from that model but I'm getting some other errors with that so probably not the best solution for this issue.

Comment: Basically post request now takes this kind of object: `{ origin_country: 1, destination: 2, status:"CLOSED"}` However instead of the ids for the origin and destination Im trying to have the names of the countries from the `Country` model.

Comment: When you write `origin_country: 1`. Does the 1 refer to the id of Country or OriginCountry ?

Comment: It refers to the `OriginCountry` model, so it will be different than destination id. However the base is still `Country`.

Comment: @Guillaume I updated the question with OriginCountry structure, maybe it will help

Comment: I tried using SlugRelatedField and this works for destionation: `destination = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), slug_field='name')`, but I cant manage to make it work for `origin_country`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. The problem is that you have no way of retrieving an Origin_country except with ID. You would need a unique field in your model to do so.

Comment: @Guillaume just adding unique field to the `OriginCountry` model would do the trick?

Comment: Yes, so you could also use the same trick with SlugField.

Comment: But there is a hidden id created for the model anyways, should I declare it explicitly?

Comment: No, using the ID as the identifier would result in what you're currently doing. I was thinking of a unique field like the name of the `origin_country` but I am not sure if it's really unique in your case.

Comment: It is unique, but it comes as a foreign key from the `Country` model

Comment: Then you should use a OneToOneField rather than a FK. After that there might be a way of retrieving the instance with origin_country__name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I will try to give this combination.

You get this error because of **Incorrect Type** exception. Django checks data type validation on the serializer. For example here your dest_country returns a **list of dicts** but in your model it is a **primary key (pk)**

That's why on post django says : **pk value expected, list received**

> But you can solve this error by using two different serializers (one to post another by default)

### 1. Create two different serializers

```py
class BorderStatusEditorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """The First serialiser by default"""
    origin_country = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    destination = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BorderStatus
        fields = ('origin_country', 'destination', 'status')



class BorderStatusEditorCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """The Second serialiser for create"""

    class Meta:
        model = BorderStatus
        fields = ('origin_country', 'destination', 'status')
```

### 2.Add get_serializer_class method to for Viewset

```py
class BorderStatusViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BorderStatus.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields=('origin_country','destination')

    serializer_classes = {
        'create': BorderStatusEditorCreateSerializer, # serializer used on post
    }
    default_serializer_class = BorderStatusEditorSerializer # Your default serializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_classes.get(self.action, self.default_serializer_class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override `perform_create` method of the viewset to make the necessary adjustments on-the-fly when new entry is posted:

```
class BorderStatusViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BorderStatus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BorderStatusEditorSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields=('origin_country','destination')

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        origin_country, _ = models.Country.get_or_create(name=self.request.data.get('origin_country')
        destination, _ = models.Country.get_or_create(name=self.request.data.get('destination')
        return serializer.save(origin_country=origin_country, destination=destination)
```

Maybe you will also need to adjust your serializer to have:

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ['name']


class BorderStatusEditorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    origin_country = CountrySerializer()
    destination = CountrySerializer()
    ...
```